# NRWL NX library typescript ambient declaration files

Tags: typescript, types, nrwl, ambient

I have a basic setup in my new NX workspace

- /apps/my-app (node type)
- /libs/some-lib (node type)

Both created with nx cli commands:
i.e. *nx g @nrwl/node:lib some-lib --simpleModuleName=true*

For library I wanted to use ambient declaration files (.d.ts).
I added one in */libs/some-lib/src/types/index.d.ts*,
with content:

```
declare type MyCustomType = any;
```

As I understand, this file gets processed based on */libs/some-lib/tsconfig.lib.json* file, but I also added direct reference to this file in */libs/some-lib/tsconfig.json*:

```
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.base.json",
    "files": [
        "src/types/index.d.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/types/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
        },
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

My IDE is happy when I'm using this file inside lib's code, for example:
*/libs/some-lib/src/lib/file.ts*

```
export const x: MyCustomType = 1;
```

But if I want to import this variable into **my-app** and I run it (**nx serve my-app**),

```
import { x } from '@my-workspace/some-lib';
```

I get an error from the compiler:

```
ERROR in libs/some-lib/src/lib/file.ts
TS2304: Cannot find name "MyCustomType".
```

So my question is, is there a way to use ambient declaration files inside libraries and not to get errors when running application that imports abstractions from this library?

I could create in the root folder shared types: *types/myCustomType.d.ts" and then include it in the application's and library's tsconfigs in files property, but I wan't to avoid it and keep types close to the code.

Another solution that works, but is ugly as hell is to add additional reference to the library in my-app's tsconfig file:

```
{
    "path": "../../libs/some-lib/tsconfig.json"
}
```

Result */apps/my-app/tsconfig.json*:

```
{
      "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
      "files": [],
      "include": [],
      "references": [
        {
          "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
          "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
        },
        {
          "path": "../../libs/node/schedulers/tsconfig.json"
        }
      ]
}
```

Or create a *tsconfig.json* barrel: */libs/tsconfig.json* ... and just reference relevant libraries there. my-app's tsconfig file would only need to reference this single file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a root directory for all types `types/`
Create sub-directories for apps and libs

- `types/lib-a/`
- `types/lib-b/`
- `types/app-a/`

No need to add these type to the `tsconfig.base.json`. Revert all your tsconfig files to the defaults and then add the `typeRoots` in each library and applications' `tsconfig.json` files. Also include the typeRoots for the libraries it depends on.

1. `libs/lib-a/tsconfig.lib.json`

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["../../../types/lib-a/"]
    },
    ...
}
```

2. `libs/lib-b/tsconfig.lib.json`

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["../../../types/lib-b/"]
    },
    ...
}
```

3. `apps/app-a/tsconfig.app.json` also add the dependent libraries' types here

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "../../../types/lib-a/",
            "../../../types/app-a/"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```